# How do I create a approval workflow for an infopath list

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I have created a form using infopath which currently sends the contents as an email when the submit button is pushed.

How would I integrate an approval workflow with this form, so that when the submit button is pushed the approval workflow begins and the email sent contains an "approve or reject" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your submit button operates in the standard manner (i.e. submitting saves the form to the library or list) then you would simply need to change the start up behavior of the workflow.

You can change the workflow startup options from workflow settings page.

Also Check:
http://sharepointbeeeye.com/infopath-2010-starting-workflow-on-click-event/

OR you can do:

Simply add a field to your form called my:Status and set its value (via rules) when the user clicks Save or Submit. Promote this field, i.e. make it a promoted property.

Then, in the SharePoint form library, you can use the value of Status to determine whether the workflow starts or not. If Status = Submitted, start the workflow. Otherwise, don't start the workflow.